# Schengen visa: Must I enter and leave the Schengen area in the same country?

Tags: visas, schengen, uk-citizens

I live in London and 
am planning to visit France and Brussels. I'm applying in French embassy, showing hotel booking in France and I will stay there three nights and 4th day morning I will travel to Brussels and will leave Brussels around evening.

Do I need to go back to Paris for coming back to London or can I directly a take train from Brussels to London? 
Also do I need to show (to the embassy) a ticket for traveling to Brussels from Paris?

Comment: You might want to add information on your and your husband's nationality. Assuming you'll have a Schengen visa to go to Paris, you will not need to return to Paris, but can go straight from Brussels to London.

Comment: @greyshade I can imagine a few (rather unusual) scenarios in which going to Brussels is not possible but can't think of any where going to Brussels is allowed but going back to Paris is required.

Comment: @Relaxed am I misreading you or are you indeed confirming my statement? (and saying you can imagine a few cases where going to Brussels would be impossible is always worth less than outlining them?;))

Comment: @greyshade Indeed, we seem to be in violent agreement. I must have misread your original comment. I don't think the nationality makes a difference, though, and we already know the OP needs a visa.

Answer (score 6):

You can enter and leave wherever you want, as long as your journey makes sense and really includes France as its main destination.

Formally, you don't need to show the embassy any ticket at all but the more you can provide, the better. At least explain your itinerary and include your tickets in and out of the area (so the ticket from Brussels to London), if you have them.

Consulates do appreciate a coherent and plausible itinerary but Brussels and Paris are common destinations and close to each other so I don't think that how you intend to go from one to the other will be an issue at all.